# Set Nagios to alert if a threshold is exceeded over time?

Tags: nagios, system-monitoring, alerting

I have a server with a memory value that I want to monitor. If the value is over a certain amount over the course of an hour, I'd like to have an alert sent, but until then I'd like to have it ignore the plugin alert.

Is it possible to have Nagios alert only if a plugin has detected an issue for more than X number of minutes? (Or alternatively alert only if X number of warnings are gathered from the plugin?)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't exactly a way to achieve "alert if this is a problem for an hour", but you can get close by understanding [how checks and states work](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/statetypes.html).

The time between "problem" and "notification" mostly depends on `check_interval`, `retry_interval`, and `max_check_attempts`.